# MYSQL output only result according to the latest time

Tags: mysql

This is the database:

```
to     from     time
A      B        2015-01-02 12:00:30
B      A        2015-01-02 12:30:40
A      B        2015-01-02 12:20:30
A      C        2015-01-02 13:00:30
C      A        2015-01-02 13:20:30
```

How to output the following results:

```
to     from     time
B      A        2015-01-02 12:30:40
C      A        2015-01-02 13:20:30
```

So I'm after the row holding the latest time for each pair of correspondents.

THX!

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected result?

Comment: how many no of latest time you want??

Comment: you have written wrong out put or wrong explanation on subject

Comment: please provide more details of the question like what is the logic..what query you have tried.

Comment: Seems clear enough to me. The OP wants the latest time for each pair of correspondents. The only thing that is unclear is the PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good.
"to" and "from" contain "a", the other fields may be "b", "c", "d" and so on.
I hope that the only record of chronological order "a" and other fields.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want the latest time for each pair, but the order of the elements doesn't matter, so (a, b) and (b, a) are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT to, from, time
FROM table
WHERE time IN (SELECT max(time)
               FROM table
               GROUP BY HOUR(time))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the effect I want

Answer (score -1):

```
select top(2) * from table order by time desc
```

if time is not sorted properly you can do

```
select top(2) * from table order by cast( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, ':', 1), ':', -1) as int)*60+Cast( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, ':', 2), ':', -1) as int) desc
```

Comment: Mysql does not support the `SELECT TOP` statement.